# Redirect to another url using pop up window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The problem is when i click the reserve link in the popup window

[image]

the popup window is the one who redirects to another link

[image]

how can I redirect the encircled url below to Admin/reserve.php?

[image]

here is my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function openWin()
   {

    myBtn=window.open('','','width=200,height=200');
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
    myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");
    myBtn.document.write('<a href="Admin/reserve.php">Reserve</a>');;
    myBtn.focus();



    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
window.name = "_oldWindow";
myBtn=window.open('','_NewWindow ','width=200,height=200');
myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Name: Esperanza</p>");
myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Price: P800,000</p>");
myBtn.document.write("<p>Lot Size: 50 sq. metres</p>");
myBtn.document.write('<a href="Admin/reserve.php" target="_oldWindow">Reserve</a>');;
myBtn.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, I wouldn't recommend this for most applications

You can replace the last document.write with this

```
myBtn.document.write('<a href="javascript:window.opener.parent.main.location.href=\"/tola/Admin/reserve.php\"; return false;">Reserve</a>');
```

My recommendation would be to have the initial window.open to actually open another html-based target file, and then code proper javascript in it to call window.opener... You can place in proper verifications, like

```
<script>
var opener = window.opener;
if (opener) {
    opener.parent.main.location.href="/tola/Admin/reserve.php";
}
</script>
```

I believe the (.)parent reference is optional, and its placed there in case you're calling from within an iFrame.

Comment: it seems like its not doing something i put the javascript code below, am I wrong?

Comment: there might be a Javascript error of some sort.  Inspect your browser's console (e.g. in Chrome -> View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) for more info